# Only show distinct entries

Tags: channel-entries

Is there a way to only show distinct entries using the channel entries tag?

For example, I want to create a list of channel entries that have a city field. The list would show the city name, but there are several entries that would have the same city name. If I use the channel entries tag to display the cities, their would be duplicates.

How do I avoid the duplicates?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: First, looks like to use categories is a better solution than to use fields for cities. Second, one entry per city?

Comment: Do you have a code sample of what you are trying to do? Or are you able to provide more details to help describe what you are trying to do?

Comment: Categories would do the trick but was hoping to avoid using categories. I think the query module may be the ticket. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you would like to avoid the duplicates while showing only cities, you can use Query module to populate the cities. Like:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT DISTINCT field_id_xxx AS city_name FROM exp_channel_data WHERE channel_id=x"}

{city_name}

{/exp:query}
```

You need to replace field_id_xxx with correct custom field id.

Comment: just updated my query. Forgot DISTINCT within SQL.

Comment: Yep, DISTINCT is probably faster than GROUP BY

Answer (score 0):

As Bhashkar says, you can use the query module to do this. However to avoid showing duplicates you will need to add a GROUP clause;

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT field_id_xxx AS city_name FROM exp_channel_data WHERE channel_id=x GROUP BY field_id_xxx"}

{city_name}

{/exp:query}
```

This will ensure that each city name is shown only once

Comment: `GROUP BY field_id_xxx` will result in identical output to performing a `DISTINCT field_id_xxx` in the SELECT, in this instance...